# GUI hangs even after using threading pygtk

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pygtk, gtk3

I am writing an email application. When I send an email my main GUI thread hangs even tho, I have created a separate thread to send the email. I think I have miss-understood threading?

I have GObject function start_init() at the beginning of the main thread. I don't need threads_enter() and threads_leave(), because the thread is doing to changes to my GUI.

I know there are lot of question on threading, but as a beginner  I was not able to follow them. What am I doing wrong here?

**Class to send Email**

```
class EmailSendThread(Thread):

  def __init__(this, email):
    Thread.__init__(this)
    this.email = email


  def run(this):
    this.email.send_email()
```

**On button send Press**

```
def on_btn_Send_clicked(this, *args):

  Ethread = EmailSendThread(this.application.email)
  Ethread.setName('SendEmailThread')

  Ethread.start()
  Ethread.join()
```

**Application init**

```
GObject.threads_init()
EasyMail = EasyMailApplication()

Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.join` makes the main program wait until the thread finishes executing. If you don't want the main program to sit there waiting, don't call `join`.

Comment: But, if the main program terminates before the thread send email is complete then ?

Comment: Then `join` on the thread as the very last command in the program.

Comment: OK, let me try it out!

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia You're not creating `EmailSendThread` as a `daemon`, so the program will stay alive until that thread completes, even if the main thread is finished.